# how use props.children with ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new in typescript and I try to use correctly props.children with typescript but i get an error.

```
interface IFetcher {
  url: string;
}

const Fetcher: React.FC<IFetcher> = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Array<{}>>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {...})

  return props.children(data, error, isLoading);
};
```

this is the erreur on props.children : ***Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.***

i use this trick for resolv it :

```
interface IFetcher {
  url: string;
}

const Fetcher: React.FC<IFetcher> = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Array<{}>>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {...})

  return props.children && props.children(data, error, isLoading);
};
```

but i have another erreur :

***this expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'string | number | true | {} | ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal' is callable.***

I need help for use the good way plz.

**EDIT**
I found this solution :

```
interface IFetcher {
  url: string;
  children(data: Array<{}>, error: string, isLoading: boolean): ReactElement;
}

const Fetcher: React.FC<IFetcher> = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Array<{}>>([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {...});

  return props.children(data, error, isLoading);
};
```

When i define children i have no erreur now but is this the right solution ?

Comment: apparently `function` is not included in the default `children` types (Should it not be?). `React.FC<T>` does an overwite combine so this way you can overwrite the default type of the `children` prop.

Comment: how do we do that?

Answer (score 14):

When you trying to call children props as a function you must be sure that children exists. In order for you to impose a typecheck on children, you need to provide it in interface

```
interface IFetcher {
  url: string;
  children(data: Array<{}>, error: string, isLoading: boolean): ReactElement;
}

const Fetcher: React.FC<IFetcher> = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Array<{}>>([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {...});

  return props.children(data, error, isLoading);
};
```

Comment: indeed, that's what I found. the "problem" was children is defined with children?.

Comment: What do you mean A Vincent?